# Difference in meaning between anybody and somebody in a specific context

Tags: difference, pronouns

What is the difference in meaning between these two senstences?

> Tom wants to see **anybody**.
> Tom wants to see **somebody**.

Comment: Are you asking this because you're having trouble knowing, in general, when to choose between "anybody" and "somebody"? Or, are you interested in the differences between these two specific sentences? If it's these two sentences, then please edit your question to add the context because they mean different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see **anybody**, clearly any person will fit who may be able to assist you. The context may make it clearer.

You may say something like: **I'd like to see anybody who knows something about computer problems**, although **somebody** would fit equally well.

If you want to see **somebody**, it's nearly always in a context where you are looking for an appropriate person to assist you with a problem, typically in a government department, a company, a store, a hospital or the police.

Although the request is not specific, it implies a person able to deal with an inquiry, request or complaint.

**I'd like to see somebody about the non delivery of my order.**
**I'd like to see somebody about the behaviour of my neighbour.**

Comment: Right on about the neighbor. Where I live, we could not get action on that. [a joke but true]

Answer (score 0):

*Anybody* (and other expressions using *any*) are most often used in negative polarity contexts (negative and interrogative), where they replaces *somebody* and similar expressions.

When you use them in a positive context, they add an implication of "it doesn't matter who/what/which".

So of your two sentences

> Tom wants to see somebody.

is neutral: it doesn't convey anything about who Tom wants to see, or how he feels about it, except that he wants to see them. Without context, you can't tell if there is a particular person Tom has in mind or not: it might have either meaning.

> Tom wants to see anybody.

is not neutral: there is something extra. It implies that Tom doesn't care who he sees, as long as he sees somebody.

It often suggests that Tom is feeling anxious, impatient or desperate: maybe there is nobody around, and he's hoping he can find *somebody* to see. Maybe he's had a whole lot of problems, so he just wants to *see* someone who can help, or even just listen.

(Note that I haven't used *anybody* in my explanations: it wouldn't fit in any of my sentences0.